# Grails Gorm find retrieves different date value compared from database

Tags: oracle, grails, groovy

In my Oracle database, there is an `Agreement` table with a column `effectivityDate` with a data type of `DATE`. When I try to query a certain row

```
select * from agreement where id = 'GB'
```

it returns a row with this value:

```
id: GB
name: MUITF - Double bypass
...
effectivityDate: 7/2/2015
```

I created a `Grails` `Domain` class for this:

```
class Agreement implements Serializable {
    String id
    Date effectivityDate

    static mapping = {
        table "agreement"
        varsion: false
        id column: "id"
        name column: "name"
        ...
        effectivityDate column: "effectivityDate"
    }
}
```

But when I tried to query it on `groovy` using:

```
Agreement a = Agreement.findById("GB")
println a
```

It return this object:

```
[id:GB, name:MUITF - Double bypass, ..., effectivityDate: 2015-07-01T16:00:00Z]
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My question is, why would the date fetched directly from the database different from the one retrieved by `gorm`? Does this have something to do with time zones?

Comment: To exclude very trivial causes, please try in SQL     `select to_char(effectivityDate,'ddmmyyyy hh24miss') effectivityDate from agreement where id = 'GB'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just seen in your profile you are from Philippines (PHT, GMT+8).

Since `2015-07-01T16:00:00Z === 2015-07-02T00:00:00+08:00`, the most likely cause is that you are using the PHT time zone to display the date when querying the database and the GMT/Zulu time zone when querying/displaying with groovy/grails.